# Schema Changes Are Not Populating to The Subscribers

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge

One of my publications was dropped mistakenly. I restored it from the latest backup but now schema changes are not replicated to the subscribers.

What can I do to re-initialize/fix the publication?

Comment: Did you reinitialized publication after you restored it?

Comment: Can you explain `restored it from the latest backup`? How did you restore? How do you know the options are all same?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean afterwards you re-created the publication that you dropped? Afterwards, did you started back the snapshot agent?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore a publication from the latest backup, but you then have to re-publish it.  The snapshot agent has to be restarted.